# Graphviz drawings partly cropped

Tags: graphviz, dot, neato

I am using Graphviz to draw graphs from adjacency matrices and in some situations I get a .ps file in which the graph appears partly cropped. Like this:
[image: Cropped graph :(]

This is highly annoying and unusable. Can someone please explain what is going on and how to work around this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason you need to have postscript? Have you considered other formats? e.g.

```
  neato.exe myfile.dot -Tpng -O
  neato.exe myfile.dot -Tsvg -O
```

http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/output.html

Comment: Eventually, I want to put the graphs into Latex documents, so ps is the easiest for me on terms of workflow. But I'll try ypur suggestion and report back the result.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem of cropped output. Solved it by outputting in png format

```
dot -Tpng myfile.dot -o ~/output.png
```

OR

```
`command that generates *.dot` | dot -Tpng -o ~/output.png
```

If the output node sizes are too small to see increase their size using `-Gsize` argument